# Vagrant: dynamically selecting config.vm.box depending on host CPU (32 vs 64 bits)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to create a Vagrantfile by setting up config.vm.box to a given base image from Vagrant Cloud.

The same image is available for 32 and 64 bits (e.g ubuntu/trusty64 and ubuntu/trusty32)

Is there a way I could make that Vagrantfile configuration dynamic enough so the right image would be selected depending on the host CPU?

Alternatively,are there any parameters clients could specify when doing the "vagrant up" to select  their right option (32 vs 64 bits)?

My goal is that using the same Vagrantfile someone running Win64 would get 64bits image from Vagrant Cloud, but someone running Win32 could get the 32bits instead when doing "vagrant up"

Just specifying a 64bits images does not work as VirtualBox would not be able to run it...

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Hi @danielmacho72, what about using ENV variables? `VAGRANT_MACHINE=32 vagrant up`

Comment: Ok, I will test that Marc! Thanks, sometimes the answer is closer than it seems to... ;-)